# Ajax call on link click while NOT preventing default browser behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make an Ajax call with jQuery when a link is clicked. The link opens in a new tab, so I don't want to use `preventDefault()` on the link click. Rather, I want the Ajax call to be fired on click and keep the usual browser behavior intact.

**The code:**

HTML

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" class="js-my-link" data-id="13">CLICK ME</a>
```

JS

```
$('.js-my-link').on('click', function() {

    $.post('/track', {id: $(this).data('id')}, function() {});

});
```

The question is: **Are there any cross-browser concerns that the Ajax call would not be fired in my case?**

Comment: No. It should work

Comment: Yeah, especially that the link opens in a new tab, so the tab with the Ajax call actually stays open long enough for the call to be fired. I'm just asking because maybe, just maybe, some browsers will not fire following event handlers if a link is clicked. But it does seem unlikely.

Comment: There are extensions that disable `traget="_blank"` so that the user can always decide if they want to open the link in the same window, a new tab or a new window. So there might be be users out there for whom the ajax might not fire.